# PHP: get rank value and convert in level - function()

Tags: php, math, operators

I got a function that must to convert a rank value (i.e. 35 exp) and convert into the related level (i.e. Level 2)

```
function level($rank) {
        if ( $rank  = 0    && $rank >= 5    )   { $level = 1; }
    elseif ( $rank <= 6    && $rank >= 20   )   { $level = 2; }
    elseif ( $rank <= 21   && $rank >= 50   )   { $level = 3; }
    elseif ( $rank <= 51   && $rank >= 100  )   { $level = 4; }
    elseif ( $rank <= 101  && $rank >= 500  )   { $level = 5; }
    elseif ( $rank <= 501  && $rank >= 1000 )   { $level = 6; }
    elseif ( $rank <= 1001 && $rank >= 2500 )   { $level = 7; }
    elseif ( $rank <= 2501 && $rank >= 5000 )   { $level = 8; }

    return $level;
}
```

But this don't work, i got undefined value for `$level`.

Where is the error? Thanks to all who can help

Comment: How it possible      if ( $rank  = 0    && $rank >= 5    )

Comment: learn the difference between `=` and `==` when used in an `if()`... you trash the rank value so **ALL** ranks become `0`, because you have `$rank = 0` instead of `$rank == 0`. since a rank can't be both `0` and simultaneously bigger than `5`, none of those tests succeed, and $level ends up undefined.

Comment: Second  $rank = 0 ??? Its not comparing

Comment: For undefined add else{$level = "";}

Answer (score 2):

`=`is for assignation

`==` is for comparison

```
function level($rank) {
        if ( $rank  => 0    && $rank <= 5    )   { $level = 1; }
    elseif ( $rank >= 6    && $rank <= 20   )   { $level = 2; }
    elseif ( $rank >= 21   && $rank <= 50   )   { $level = 3; }
    elseif ( $rank >= 51   && $rank <= 100  )   { $level = 4; }
    elseif ( $rank >= 101  && $rank <= 500  )   { $level = 5; }
    elseif ( $rank >= 501  && $rank <= 1000 )   { $level = 6; }
    elseif ( $rank >= 1001 && $rank <= 2500 )   { $level = 7; }
    elseif ( $rank >= 2501 && $rank <= 5000 )   { $level = 8; }

    return $level;
}
```

You could also create the function to make it easier and avoid multiple conditions

```
<?php

function getLevel($rank) {
    $levels = [
        [
            'minimum' => 0,
            'maximum' => 5,
            'level'   => 0
        ],
        [
            'minimum' => 6,
            'maximum' => 10,
            'level'   => 1
        ],
        [
            'minimum' => 11,
            'maximum' => 20,
            'level'   => 2
        ],
    ];

    foreach($levels as $level) {
        if($rank >= $level['minimum'] && $rank <= $level['maximum'])
            return $level['level'];
    }

    return 'Infinite';
}
```

Comment: U fixed the ist condition also chk other conditions

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `<=` for first condition in every `if` statement. Try switching it to `>=`

Answer (score 1):

You have typos and major logic flaws.

1)

```
    if ( $rank  = 0    && $rank >= 5    )   { $level = 1; }
                 ^--should be ==
```

2)

```
elseif ( $rank <= 6    && $rank >= 20   )   { $level = 2; }
               ^----------------^
```

explain how a single number can be both **LESS** than 6, and simultaneously **LARGER** than 20...

Comment: True how a variable contains two values at a time ... Valid point

Answer (score 0):

I would define an array because your if's can become too complicated:

```
function level($userRank) {
    $ranks = array(
        1=>array('min'=>0,'max'=>5),
        2=>array('min'=>6,'max'=>20),
    );

    foreach($ranks as $level=>$rank) {
        if($rank['min']<= $userRank && $rank['max']>= $userRank) {
            return $level;
        }
    }

}
```